# How to take user input to create another instance of a class? (i.e. add an employee from user specifications?)

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding, and I'm still confused about how to approach this. I want to make an employee database that can, depending on user input 1: look up an employee, 2: add an employee, 3: change an existing employee's info, and 4: list all employees.

I can get the first and last specifications to work (albeit messily), but I'm having trouble with 2 and 3. I'm also unsure about the right way to store my employee instances, or if I should store them in a dictionary instead. Any pointers of how to start steps 2 and 3 would be great!

I've tried looking up a few different solutions, as well as reading articles about classes and/or dictionaries, but I'm unfortunately lost.

Defining the class:

```````py
class Employee:
```def __init__(self, name, salary, department, title):
``````self.name = name
``````self.salary = salary
``````self.department = department
``````self.title = title

```def tell(self):
``````print('{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.name, self.salary, self.department, self.title), end="")

```def add_employee(self, addname, addsalary, adddepartment, addtitle):
``````self.name, self.salary, self.department, self.title.append(addname, 
``````addsalary, adddepartment, addtitle)
```````

The above is nested under the class; the last line is an attempt to make an add_employee function that adds employee details from user_input to the pre-set instances. I don't think this code is correct, either.

The following is a function outside of the class, as well as the three pre-set employee instances; my guess is this is also bad code (oof):

````py
def add_employee_input():

```Employee.add_employee(input("Enter name:"), input("Enter salary:"), input("Enter department:"),input("Enter title:"))
```print("The full roster is as follows:")
```emp1.tell()
```emp2.tell()
```emp3.tell()
```emp4.tell()

emp1 = Employee('Angela', '40000', 'Department for Penguin Research', 'Penguinologist')
emp2 = Employee('Mr. Rogers', '60000', 'Admin', 'Manager')
emp3 = Employee('Lucie', '50000', 'Department for Snail Research', 'Snailologist')
emp4 = Employee(addname, addsalary, adddepartment, addtitle)
````

I know the last line is wrong; I don't know if I can directly insert a variable into a class instance like this. And I doubt the function is correct, either.

If I try to run the code without the add_employee function blocked off, I get an error message about how the "addname," "addsalary," etc. variables are undefined. This makes sense to me, since I'm trying to incorporate local class variables to an outside function. I don't know how to do it otherwise, but I'm sure there's a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs an employee to set differents part of it

```py
def add_employee_input(employee: Employee):
  employee.name = input("Name:")
  #And so on

#main
myEmployee = Employee(...) #needs empty constructor
add_employee_input(myEmployee)
```

But as you can see your employee needs parameters (because you have no empty constructor)

So add

```py
class Employee:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "DefaultName"
    # And so on
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this long/confusing post. I think I understand what you mean, but I'm confused on the parameters--do I add the "Default Name" etc. parameters under the original Employee class? I'm also a bit clueless on empty constructors or what is happening during this code. Should I eliminate the def add_employee function (nested under the class in my original code), since it's referencing undefined variables? Thank you so much again!

Comment: The thing i that your function require an existing employee. But you have yet no way to create a "default" one. Either add an epty constructor (with no param as written in the post). Either create one with default values like ```employee = Employee("name",0,"dpt","tile")```. These attributes will be replaced by the input ones :)

Comment: @Comet: just so you know, there is an acceptance system here. It's not mandatory, but it is helpful - where an answer was the solution you needed, click on the tick/check mark to its left, so it turns green. It is the Stack Overflow way of thanking people for their effort.

Answer (score 1):

Good job so far! Let me give some suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

When you specified the `add_employee` function in the class, that's what's called an **instance method**. Note that you're taking a *self* parameter; this means that the `Employee` instance should *already* exist when you use it.

Writing `Employee.add_employee(...)` asks the `Employee` class to run the function. But the function is defined for instances, not classes! Look up the `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` decorators for creating methods that don't require instantiation.

Now, in theory you could use those decorators and handle everything inside the `Employee` class, but here's the thing: Should a regular employee know how to create itself? Also, what happens if one day you decide to not use objects for database entries, but an actual database like MySQL? These are software engineering issues, but consider the following.

There are various ways to solve this. I suggest creating a new class, `EmployeeDatabase`, that abstracts away all the database. Now, functions in the object will handle each requirement, like this:

```
class EmployeeDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        # TODO: Initialize database.
        pass
    def lookup_by_name(self, name):
        # TODO: Lookup employee by name, and return all the available information.
        pass
    def add_employee(self, name, salary, department, title):
        # TODO: Add employee to the database.
        pass
    def list_all(self):
        # TODO: List all employees in the database.
        pass
    def change_employee(self, pk):
        # TODO: Change an employee information.
        pass
```

I want to note two things. First, a database usually uses an identifier for each row, so I suggest assigning a primary key, `pk`, to each employee record. Second, this liberates you to use the implementation you want. A possible implementation would be using a list:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self._database = []
```

In this case, the primary key would just be the position of the employee in the list.

The `_` at the start of the instance variables is just a convention to say that you're not supposed to touch them from outside the instance without a method. Don't worry about it.

To add a new employee as a tuple:

```
    def add_employee(self, name, salary, department, title):
        self._database.append((name, salary, department, title))
```

I suggest that the interactive input functions stay outside the class definition. To use the class, you would do:

```
employee_database = EmployeeDatabase()

def add_employee_input(database):
    database.add_employee(
        input('Enter name:'),
        input('Enter salary:'),
        input('Enter department:'),
        input('Enter title:'),
    )

add_employee_input(employee_database)
# The output for interactive use could be something like
# "Created new employee with ID 1"
```

Can you implement the other functions?

Some last pointers:

- To look up the employee name, you would need to check the name one by one in the database. This is clearly inefficient, so databases use what's called an *index*. Of course, you could just use a dictionary where the key is the name, but what happens if two people have the same name?
- I used a tuple to represent an employee in the list. You could also continue using the `Employee` class idea, storing instances in the list. A more elegant solution would be to use a `NamedTuple`, which lets you manipulate each element with attributes, like you would in a class instance. It's part of the Python standard library.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful explanation and post about classes! I wish I could also give you a checkmark! I'm going to reread it a couple of times to make sure I digest it and understand it. I got the code to work, but I don't think it's the most elegant way, so I'll try tweaking it with your suggestions. Thank you again!